# Selecionar primeiro da lista ou valor máximo em CTE recursiva em SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursão, cte

Estou com o seguinte problema, preciso criar uma query que me retorne a hierarquia de produtos, mas na minha tabela possuo uma coluna (G1_REVFIM) que armazena o valor da revisão final. E nessa hierarquia, preciso que a query me retorne apenas os produtos com a última revisão.

Exemplo: Se embaixo de um produto X possuo três produtos

Produto A: G1_REVFIM = 18

Produto B: G1_REVFIM = 15

Produto C: G1_REVFIM = 18

Nessa caso precisaria que retornasse apenas os produtos A e B.
Pra isso criei a seguinte query:

```
WITH R AS (
SELECT
    G1.G1_COD,
    G1.G1_COMP,
    G1.G1_REVFIM
FROM SG1010 G1 WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE G1.G1_COD = '1318-LEN-CR-PS'
AND G1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
AND G1.G1_REVFIM = (
    SELECT
    TOP 1
        G1_REVFIM
    FROM SG1010 WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE G1_COD IN ('1318-LEN-CR-PS')
    AND D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
    ORDER BY G1_REVFIM DESC
)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    G1.G1_COD,
    G1.G1_COMP, 
    G1.G1_REVFIM
FROM R
JOIN SG1010 G1 WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON G1.G1_COD = R.G1_COMP
WHERE G1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
AND G1.G1_REVFIM = '018'
)
SELECT
    G1_COD,
    G1_COMP,
    G1_REVFIM
FROM R
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Onde possuo o filtro AND G1.G1_REVFIM = '018' (essa linha é apenas uma gambiarra para mostrar o resultado que eu precisaria, mas funciona apenas para esse produto em específico, se eu tivesse mais uma hierarquia abaixo de um dos produtos, ou pesquisasse outro ao invés do 1318-LEN-CR-PS, eles não seriam mostrados, pois possuem G1_REVFIM diferentes) eu precisaria de um filtro onde ordeno em ordem decrescente e seleciono o primeiro da lista, ou então um filtro que me retorne o maior valor (última revisão). Porém há várias restrições, e todas as formas que tentei para retornar esse valor são proibidas.
Usando o mesmo exemplo que dei acima, sem o filtro AND G1.G1_REVFIM = '018' na query, eu tenho como retorno A, B e C. Mas quero apenas A e C como explicado.

Tabela retornada sem AND G1.G1_REVFIM = '018'

Obs.: Não tenho permissão para colocar imagens, então vou por o link e digitar cada coluna abaixo

[Tabela 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV9NH.png)

**COLUNA G1_COD**

1318-LEN-CR-PS

1318-LEN-CR-PS

MS00300078

MS00300078

MS00300078

MS00300078

MS00300078

**COLUNA G1_COMP**

MOD1.02

MS00300078

MP00300012

MP00300042

MP00300000

MP00300042

MR00300015

**COLUNA G1_REVFIM**

003

003

014

015

018

018

018

Para melhor entendimento, G1_COD é o produto, e G1_COMP são os produtos embaixo dele, então o produto **1318-LEN-CR-PS** tem **MOD1.02** e **MS00300078**. O produto **MS00300078**, tem **MP00300012**, **MP00300042**, **MP00300000**, **MP00300042** e **MR00300015** embaixo dele, e **MOD1.02** não possui nenhum.
Então nessa minha tabela, eu não queria que fosse mostrado **MP00300012** e **MP00300042** (o que tem G1_REVFIM = 15).

Obs.:
O produto 1318-LEN-CR-PS tem outros produtos com G1_REVFIM diferentes. Mas estão sendo filtrados por essa parte.

```
    AND G1.G1_REVFIM = (
    SELECT
    TOP 1
        G1_REVFIM
    FROM SG1010 WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE G1_COD IN ('1318-LEN-CR-PS')
    AND D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
    ORDER BY G1_REVFIM DESC
)
```

Caso fosse permitido, eu simplesmente replicaria esse filtro no **SELECT** depois do **UNION ALL**. Esse filtro funciona apenas no primeiro produto, na parte da recursão não consegui fazer um filtro semelhante que seja permitido.

Exemplo com mais níveis de hierarquia:

[Resultado obtido com minha query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Y6N.png)

[Resultado que eu gostaria de ter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn0Sp.png)

[Imagem mais visual da hierarquia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgqZy.png)

Obs.: No exemplo, o material MS00300036 possui G1_REVFIM = 002, enquanto os outros no mesmo nível dele possuem G1_REVFIM = 003, que é a última revisão. E como o material MS00300036 não deve fazer parte da hierarquia, o que está abaixo dele (MP00300022, MR00300005, MP00300036, MR00300005) também não.

De forma simplificada. o que eu queria era que fosse mostrada uma hierarquia apenas com o(s) filho(s) mais velho(s).

Comment: olá Samara, fica difícil "visualizar" o problema apenas com a sua descrição, consegue adicionar na pergunta uma tabela mostrando umas linhas da sua tabela do banco de dados para visualizar melhor como se relaciona a hierarquia?

Comment: Como não tenho permissão pra adicionar imagem, vou falar os dados por coluna (somente as relevantes)

Comment: Editei na pergunta, tem o link da imagem também para melhor visualização

Comment: Pelo q entendi, no seu exemplo existem apenas 2 níveis de hierarquia. Podem existir mais? Se sim, como seria? Vc poderia postar outro exemplo mais completo? E considerando o exemplo, qual seria o resultado esperado e quais parâmetros serão fornecidos?

Comment: Existem outros níveis também, vou colocar o link das imagens com os exemplos, vou por o que eu tenho de retorno e o que eu gostaria de ter.

Comment: Podem haver materiais com níveis maiores ainda do que o último exemplo que dei, mas um filtro que seleciona o maior valor na recursão resolveria meu problema na hierarquia inteira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo q entendi vc pode utilizar primeiro a função *Row_Number* para classificar as linhas por ordem descrecente de revisão para depois utilizar na parte recursiva somente as linhas com a última revisão:

```
WITH 
    CTE_N AS (
    SELECT
        G1.G1_COD,
        G1.G1_COMP,
        G1.G1_REVFIM,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (PARTITION BY G1.G1_COD 
             ORDER BY G1.G1_REVFIM DESC) AS RN
    FROM SG1010 G1 WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE G1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
    ),


    CTE_R AS (
    SELECT
        G1_COD,
        G1_COMP,
        G1_REVFIM
    FROM CTE_N
    WHERE G1_COD = '1318-LEN-CR-PS'
    AND RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        G1.G1_COD,
        G1.G1_COMP, 
        G1.G1_REVFIM
    FROM CTE_R R
    JOIN CTE_N G1
        ON G1.G1_COD = R.G1_COMP
    WHERE G1.RN = 1
    )

SELECT
    G1_COD,
    G1_COMP,
    G1_REVFIM
FROM CTE_R
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, mas dessa forma ele me retorna apenas um da hierarquia de casa produto, não me mostra todos. Ele me retorna MS00300078 pro G1_COD 1318-LEN-CR-PS e MP00300000 para o G1_COD MS00300078.

Comment: Vc pode postar um exemplo com uma amostra de dados da tabela no sqlfiddle? Assim ficaria melhor para entender a questão e realizar testes

Comment: Acho q entendi o q aconteceu, experimente trocar a função `Row_Number()` pela função `Rank()` ou pela `Dense_Rank()`

Comment: Deu certooo, muito obrigada!!
Eu troquei pelo Rank()